# I have test plan with 4 thread groups in that..I want to run whole test plan multiple times..ho I can achieve that..?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I used loop count but not able to achieve that scenario using loop count.I want to e.g First thread is post and second thread is comment.I want to create one post and add comment on that.I gave number of users for post as 1 and number of user for comment as 6,So 1 user will create post and 6 user will add comment on that.And i want to run it in loop

Answer (score 0):

There is no "global" loop controller which can be applied to several Thread Groups, one of the options I can think of is using i.e. [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) or [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) so 1/6 of users will create posts and others will post comments.

Example test plan outline/demo:

[image]

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)